# Why would a Windows 10 Machine still display "Some settings are managed by your organization" after the hard drive has been reimaged?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

This should be an easy answer for most of the "Super Users" on this site. I am relatively new to the IT field. I am trying to start a home and local computer repair business and I buy old computer equipment. I have recently ran into a couple of computers that I have added memory etc.. but after reimaging the hard drive I am seeing a message when I run updates "some settings are managed by your organization". I presume that this would occur if group policies were at one time on the machine. Why after a reimage would this message still be displayed? Thanks for your knowledge.

Comment: How did you reimage the system, and where did you obtain the image originally?

Comment: I reimaged the system from a Windows 10 usb retail stick. Newegg.

Comment: If I delete all the partitions and load Windows shouldn't that work? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Ultimately, if modifications were either made with the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) **or** if any changes were made to the registry by a person *or* application that would coincide with what `gpedit.msc` could modify, you could potentially see that message.

Comment: Run5k...Would that even occur when completely wiping and reloading Windows with a clean install?

Comment: My dilemma is that I am trying to resale salvaged equipment that I have spent time on piecing together/ upgrading and don't want any issues with a purchaser asking why it is giving that message.

Comment: Although it would be unusual, the simple answer is "yes," it's still possible.  As I said before, if any person *or* application makes a change to the registry that would coincide with what `gpedit.msc` could modify, you would potentially see that message.  If you are curious enough to pursue the root cause, you could [download the Windows Group Policy Settings Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250) spreadsheet and perform searches within the worksheets for the corresponding settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I bought a "box or lot" of misc computer equipment from a local school district. It had a few older machines in it that I was trying to fix up and make a few bucks on. Just didn't want to have anyone ask me why it was giving those messages. Trying to find the right way to do it.

Comment: Seems to be a bug since 1803. The messages come and go when updates are being applied.

Comment: This message is typically displayed, when a required feature is disabled, if you have Reset the installation then this is **NOT caused by a group policy**.  You would have to provide more specifics for a detail answer to this problem to be submitted.

Comment: I agree with other posters, this is a bug I think. I recently came across the cause of this in my research, but it was unrelated to my research at the time, so I ignored it. Don’t remember why it happens now.

Comment: Does it show you this message *immediately* after reinstalling, *before* you restore any data or programs? Also, did you *fully wipe the drive* prior to reinstalling, or just do a reinstallation over the existing one without deleting all existing data first? (Hint, in the Windows Setup boot media, hit Shift+F10 to get a command prompt, then type "diskpart" to bring up the command line partitioner. Use "list disk" to figure out which disk is your hard drive, then "select disk 0" or whatever number your hard drive is, then "clean" to clear the partition table. That should be sufficient.)